# Different possible animations for WPF TreeMap

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, wpftoolkit, datavisualization.toolkit

I have created Live Market Map using `System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization` `TreeMap` control. Something like this:

[image]

Is there is any way to animate this TreeMap? Can I animate each partition separately?

How can I Drill-down to expands child items in the tree map based on level.

Suppose if I select any sector from TreeMap It will display Details of all child nodes available.
i. e When I move cursor in *"Financial Services"* region it will display all the info of its child nodes.